# Plotly two mapbox figures in a single map with different color

Tags: python, plotly

I want to plot two mapbox figures in a single map. This is what I have right now:

```
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(geo_df,
                           geojson=geo_df.geometry,
                           locations=geo_df.index,
                           color="TOTAL_POPULATION", color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Greens,
                           center={"lat": 40.7, "lon": -73.95},
                           mapbox_style="open-street-map",
                           zoom=10)
fig2 = px.scatter_mapbox(geo_df, lat="INTPTLAT", lon="INTPTLON", 
                         size="MEDIAN_VALUE", color="MEDIAN_VALUE",
                         color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Blues,
                         mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig.add_trace(fig2.data[0])
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1400,
    height=1000,
)
```

Here, I have specified different colors for the two mapbox, but its only picking the first one and applying it to both. How can I print them with different colors to improve visibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question does not present any data, I have combined the reference [example](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#basic-example-with-plotly-express) with another [example](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/#indexing-by-geojson-properties) to confirm the events.
I searched the plotly community for a solution and identified [examples](https://community.plotly.com/t/scatter-mapbox-on-top-of-choropleth-mapbox/63486/2) that would solve the issue.
The way to do this is to add a graph object choropleth map to the graph object and then add an express graph.
One issue is that the specified colormap is not valid. We are currently investigating but may not be able to reach a solution. I believe it is compatible with the solution to your question.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

px.set_mapbox_access_token(open("mapbox_api_key.txt").read())

# fig for data
df_election = px.data.election()
geojson = px.data.election_geojson()

# fig2 for data
df_car = px.data.carshare()
df_car['peak_hour2'] = df_car['peak_hour']*20

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Choroplethmapbox(geojson=geojson,
                                  z=df_election["Bergeron"],
                                  colorscale='greens',
                                  locations=df_election["district"],
                                  featureidkey="properties.district",
                                  colorbar_x=1.12,
                                  colorbar_title='election'
                          ))
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map",
                  mapbox_center={"lat": 45.5517, "lon": -73.7073},
                  mapbox_zoom=10)

map_scatter = px.scatter_mapbox(df_car,
                            lat="centroid_lat",
                            lon="centroid_lon",
                            color="peak_hour",
                            size="car_hours",
                            color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Blues,
                            size_max=15,
                            zoom=9)
fig.add_traces(list(map_scatter.select_traces()))

fig.update_layout(coloraxis={'colorbar': {'title': {'text': 'peak_hour'}}})
fig.update_layout(autosize=True, height=600, margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

[image]